# itextsharp rotate image at point

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I am using Itextsharp at work. I would like to rotate an image at the center of that image. 
I am able to get text to display with a similar strategy, but am having some issues with images

```
        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
        //I have taken this line out and used the matrix scale
        // function, with no luck
        image.ScaleAbsolute(entry.width, entry.height);
        image.RotationDegrees = -entry.rotation;
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix matrix = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, entry.left, entry.bottom);
        matrix.RotateAt(-entry.rotation, new PointF(entry.width / 2, entry.height / 2));
        contentByte.AddImage(image, matrix);
```

the image does not show up with this method.

Comment: See [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl)'s excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412928/7407793)

Comment: Also please note that you're using an old version of iText. We don't call it iTextSharp anymore. It's called iText for .NET, and the latest version is iText 7. You're using iText 5 or earlier.